# vue computed not firing when vuex state changes

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I dont know why, but my computed property is not firing when state changes.
I am dispatching actions and as a result state changes. but data is not firing at all. wanna help :(

```js
//store

mutations: {

    setStudyData(state, payload) {
      state.studyData = [...payload];
    },
  },

actions: {
    async postLogin({ state, commit, dispatch }, { userId, userPass }) {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${url}/v1/api/user/auth/signin`, {
          userId,
          userPass,
        });
        await commit("setSeq", res.data.user_seq);
        await commit("setToken", res.data.accessToken);
        await dispatch("getStudyLi");
        console.log(state.studyData); //i can see the state changes here
      } catch {
        console.log("error");
      }
    },
```

```js
 computed: {
    data(){
      console.log(this.datas) //not working
      return this.$store.state.login.studyData 
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any **this.datas** property in the code shown.

It is also important how do use the computed. It runs the computed method only if there is some call of computed value. You can not expect method to be called if you do not use **this.data** property in your component.

Comment: that means with only  ‘this.$store.state.login.studyData’ in return statement , computed property cannot be called when studyData changes?

Comment: It won't be called untill you use "this.data" inside your component.

The "data" name is reserved by vue, so you should also rename the computed.

Comment: "The "data" name is reserved by vue" - not really, this would be inconvenient. Comp `data` name is reserved in component options and referred as `this.$data` on component instance

Answer (score 0):

U can just use mapState instead, if u not gonna process your studyData anymore and save your time writing this.$store.state.login.studyData

computed: {
...mapState([
"studyData",
"studyData2",
]),
}